# cannot run django_quiz app. manage.py not found

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-1.6, django-manage.py

I was trying to install the django_quiz app that was found on github.

https://github.com/tomwalker/django_quiz

And as you can see below, i've installed all requirements. but there's no manage.py. How do i start and run the project?

```
Things I did >

Cloned the repo with git clone https://github.com/tomwalker/django_quiz.git.

Run --> pip install -r requirements.txt. 

Run --> python setup.py install

Added 'quiz', 'multichoice', 'true_false', 'essay' to INSTALLED_APPS setting.

Added url(r'^q/', include('quiz.urls')),  to urls.py.
```

NB: I'm a beginner in Django. Please help me. I'm kind of stuck here.

> Django Version : 1.6.5

```
Installed c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django_quiz_app-0.5.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for django-quiz-app==0.5.1
Searching for Pillow==2.5.0
Best match: Pillow 2.5.0
Adding Pillow 2.5.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Searching for Django==1.6.5
Best match: Django 1.6.5
Adding Django 1.6.5 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Searching for django-model-utils==2.0.3
Best match: django-model-utils 2.0.3
Adding django-model-utils 2.0.3 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Finished processing dependencies for django-quiz-app==0.5.1

C:\Users\Vaisakhan\django_quiz>python manage.py runserver
python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: where is setting.py that you have edited ?

Comment: Screenshot here --> http://pasteboard.co/1T6c3zQz.png    Files here --> http://turl.ca/xzuje    @kushtrimh

Comment: @AhmedHosny i did the editing on that test-settings.py.  NB: i'm kind of noobie here. please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this repo misses some steps. I think the steps should be as follows:

1. pip install virtualenv (you can skip this step and the next one if you are sure that there will not be any dependency error.)
2. virtualenv ~/quiz_env
   source ~/quiz_env/bin/activate
3. pip install Django==1.6.5
4. django-admin startproject quiz_project
5. `navigate to quiz_project/quiz_project, edit setting files`
6. `navigate to quiz_project/ and copy all the apps directory ('quiz', 'multichoice',....etc) inside quiz_project along with requirement.txt file`
7. `pip install -r requirements.txt`
8. `python manage.py syncdb`
9. `python manage.py makemigrations`
10. `python manage.py migrate`
11. `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: source "c:\quiz_bin\activate" to activate the environment. or check http://pymote.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install/windows_virtualenv.html. Again, the first 2 steps to ensure we are working on a clean environment. You can skip them

Comment: when I run step 8, i'm getting a traceback error. --> ImportError: No module named quiz

Comment: i'm rightnow at the top structure. where manage.py is located at.

Comment: And what are the names of the directories there? And on which line the error is raised

Answer (score 0):

Create a manage.py file and store it in the top folder of your file structure.  Replace mysite with the folder holding your django quiz code.

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: manage.py outside this folder ?  http://pasteboard.co/1T6c3zQz.png    and where is the mysite? i can't find any ! :((

Comment: put it in this folder and replace mysite with quiz

Comment: Okay. Fixed it.